# Hibernate - Let it map

Tags: java, database, hibernate

I have the following db model:

[image]

I have several subtypes of an `int`, `double`, `string` and `date` which have an abstract parent type of `templateValue`. The all have in common the `valueType`. Each `TemplateValueMap` has one `TemplateValue`. Also each `TemplateValueMap` has one `TemplateItem`. That `templateItem` has a `valueType` which is which is one of the `valueTypes` of `TemplateValue`. If the `valueType` exists one table is created. If not, no table is created.

My classes look like that:

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="valueType")
public abstract class TemplateValue implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @NotNull    
    @Size(min=1, max=32)
    private int valueType;
```

That class has several childs like(which look the same for every other class like `TemplateValueDate/Int/Double` ect.):

```
@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue(value = "stringValue") 
public class TemplateValueString extends TemplateValue  implements Serializable {

    /**
     * the int value
     */
    @NotNull
    @Size(min=1, max=32)
    @Pattern(regexp = "[A-Za-z0-9 ]*", message = "Please insert a valid String")
    @Column(name="String_value")
    private String stringValue;
```

My `TemplateValueMap` looks like that at the moment:

```
@Entity
public class TemplateValueMap implements Serializable{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    private Long id;

    @OneToOne
    private TemplateValue tempValue;

    @OneToOne
    private TemplateItems tempItem;
```

my `TemplateValueItem` looks like that:

@Entity
public class TemplateItems implements Serializable{

```
@Id
@GeneratedValue
private Long id;

@OneToOne
private TemplateValue tempValue;

private String label;

private String valueType;

private String displayType;
```

My Problem is how to tell hibernate that it should decide if one `valueType` is used to create a `value`  of the `TemplateValueString/Double/Int` or not? This value is created because of the valueType in the `TemplateValue` and is set in the `TemplateItems`

I really appreciate your answer!

**UPDATE**

[image]

Comment: I don't understand what the question is. Hibernate maps existing tables. It doesn't create new ones. And why would it?

Comment: @JBNizet Thx you very much for your answer! I reformulated my question. Pls have a look at my question!

Comment: Except for your OneToOne bidirectional association which is not mapped correctly (one of the side must have a mappedBy attribute), everything looks fine, and it will work out of the box. What is not working? Hibernate will use the discriminator value when loading a row to instantiate the appropriate subclass. When inserting a new row, it's your responsibility to create an instance of the appropriate subclass and persist it.

Comment: @JBNizet thx for your answer! I read about the concept of `joint-subclasses`. Do you think that it makes sense to use that concept in that kind of setting, because I think that the `TemplateItems` will not be mapped correctly with the correct `value` of `TemplateValue`? btw do you have an example of such a persist method?

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to make sure that the value of valueType in TemplateValue matches with the value of valueType in TemplateItem. That's a functional requirement that Hibernate won't help you to fulfill. It's your responsibility to avoid attching a string template value to a date template item. Given everything is linked with OneToOne association, why are you duplicating this information in two diferent places?

Comment: @JBNizet I am duplicating it because in my program, I have to entry points, one for the product and one for the template of the product. I updated the extended version of the db model.